# Is there a code for saving your codes on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

```
let dairy = [];

function records(events,experience) { dairy.push({events,experience});
};
```

How do I save my functions , so I don’t have to write my codes after a shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [the getting started guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) which directs you to write code in a text file with a `.js` file extension and then run it with `node yourfilename.js` and not to just type everything in the REPL.